# If every event is trivial (0 or 1 probability), then every random variable is (a.s.) degenerate/constant. Maybe Lebesgue decomposition?

Tags: probability, distributions, measure-theory

There are these: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304541/trivial-probability-spaces-and-binomially-distributed-random-variable), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963289/p-trivial-sigma-algebra), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887782/if-a-probability-space-has-no-measurable-subsets-with-p-strictly-between-0-a), but I wanna try different ways.

Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, \mathbb P)$ be such probability space with each (event) $E \in \mathfrak F$ having trivial probability. Consider a random variable $X$.

---

An attempt:

Show that $X$ is almost surely equal to $c = \inf\{x:F_{X}(x)=1\}$, with $F_X$ as cdf (cumulative distribution function or, well, just distribution function) of $X$.

Actually $c$ is finite. If $c=\pm \infty$, then $(x:F_{X}(x)=1) = \emptyset$ or $\mathbb R$. Then $F_X(x) < 1 \ \forall x$ or $F_X(x) = 1 \ \forall x$.

By definition of such *finite* c, $$P(X \le c) = F_X(c) = 1 = F_X(d) \forall \ d \ge c$$

Now either $P(X \ge c) = 1$, in which case we're done or $P(X \ge c) = 0$.

Now $P(X \ge c) = 0 \to P(X < c) = 1 \to \exists \ d < c$ s.t. $P(X \le d) = 1$

But $\forall \ d < c$,

$$P(X \le d) = F_X(d) < 1 \to P(X \le d) = 0$$

---

**Question 1**: Is this correct?

---

**Question 2**: Is there perhaps an even simpler way to go about this namely **without guessing** what the constant $c$ is?

Actually, what I might try to do is show the $c$ exists and *then later* (not sure if I have to 1st show $c$ is finite for this next part) say it's the infimum (minimum actually? idk) of when the cdf reaches 1.

I think to consider any extended real $a$ and then the event $\{X=a\}$. Well, we can't have $P(X=a)=1$ for more than 1 extended real $a$. But from this, all we can say is that $P(X=a)=1$ for *at most* one possible $a$.

Of course it's possible we don't have $P(X=a)=1$ for any $a$, i.e. we have $P(X=a)=0$ for all $a$ such as when $X$ is a continuous(/an absolutely continuous or whatever) random variable. (But I guess this is easy to show for every discrete random variable [even if we don't assume finite] ?)

But if $X$ were continuous then $P(X \in (g,h)) = 1$ means...yeah you could probably argue a contradiction here to show continuous random variables don't exist in such a probability space (and apparently neither do [binomial distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304541/trivial-probability-spaces-and-binomially-distributed-random-variable)) but in higher probability of course not all random variables are either discrete or continuous.

Well, maybe this simpler approach works for only half the battle namely the at most 1 part, but the at least 1 part really requires more.

- **Note**: Simpler need not mean easier/less machinery. Could be more difficult/more machinery. Like perhaps **Lebesgue's decomposition theorem** can be used? What I understand of this theorem is that every random variable basically has a 'continuous part' and a 'discrete part' (Eg [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/544517/discrete-and-continuous-variables-what-is-the-definition) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468806/how-to-decompose-a-cdf-into-discrete-and-continuous-parts)). Maybe I can somehow show that in such a probability space every random variable is discrete and then (immediately?) conclude every random variable is a.s. constant?

Comment: What is the problem with considering the events $\{X \le a\}$?  They should have probability $1$ for some $a$ and $0$ for other $a$

Comment: ah thanks! so basically that's what i'm doing in the attempt? like either they're all 1 so $X=-\infty$ a.s., they're all 0 so $X = \infty$ a.s. or they're all 1 before some $a$ and all 1 after $a$ and then this 3rd case $a$ is such $\inf$ and then we somehow rule out 1st and 2nd cases?

Comment: Argue the contrapositive.  That means assuming $X$ is a random variable that is *not* a.s. constant.  Show this means there is a number $x$ for which $\Pr(X\le x) \gt 0$ and $\Pr(X\gt x) \gt 0.$  Derive a contradiction from this.  Although of course you can use "machinery," that's not an effective question because it's personal and subjective: what constitutes "machinery" depends on what you know, how you know it, and how you think of it.

Comment: @whuber i just knew there had to be something simpler. i mean hell $c=\inf\{\cdot\}$? come on! thanks! you can post as answer Edit: wait at least for question 2. what's the answer to question 1 please?

Comment: You did a good job with #1, because you thought of proving that $c$ has to exist (that is, is finite).

Comment: @whuber why thank you! ok you can post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argue the contrapositive. That means assuming X is a random variable that is not a.s. constant. Show this means there is a number x for which Pr(X≤x)>0 and Pr(X>x)>0. Derive a contradiction from this. Although of course you can use "machinery," that's not an effective question because it's personal and subjective: what constitutes "machinery" depends on what you know, how you know it, and how you think of it. –
whuber
♦

@whuber i just knew there had to be something simpler. i mean hell c=inf{⋅}? come on! thanks! you can post as answer Edit: wait at least for question 2. what's the answer to question 1 please? –
BCLC

You did a good job with #1, because you thought of proving that c has to exist (that is, is finite). –
whuber
♦